# docker with mysql not working on new ec2 arm based instance - no matching manifest

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

```
[nir ~]$ docker run --name mysql -d mysql:5.7
Unable to find image 'mysql:5.7' locally
5.7: Pulling from library/mysql
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
[nir ~]$ docker run --name mysql -d mysql:8
Unable to find image 'mysql:8' locally
8: Pulling from library/mysql
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

we upgraded to a newer instance type in aws to arm based - m6g

Looking [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318) it looks like there is nothing I can do revert to intel based instance. Is that so?

Comment: mariadb supports `linux/arm64/v8` as listed [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated). So maybe you can use mariadb?

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

`mysql` docker **does not support** `linux/arm64/v8`. However, `mariadb` [supports](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated) `linux/arm64/v8`. Thus, if possible, change of of `mysql` into `mariadb` could solve the problem.

Comment: how to do this with command?

Comment: @Sushilzzz Please make new question specific to your issue.